# Create database entry with viewable history?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm part of a small group, and I'm creating a site for our app. We've decided it would be useful to have a bugtracker, with the below table structure (called `bug_summary`):

```
bug_id    Summmary    Details        Assigned Dev
------    --------    -------        ------------
1         Bug 1       Broken         Scott
2         Bug 2       Add Feature    Dave
3         Bug 3       Design Bug     Jimmy
4         Bug 4       Broken         Carly
```

I'd like to have another table that will specifically hold updates entered by the devs, but still "linked" to the ID. Let's say there's 5 updates in the `bug_update` table.

```
update_details    bug_id_for_update
--------------    -----------------
Jan 1st update    2
Jan 2nd update    2
Jan 2nd update    1
Jan 2nd update    4
Jan 4th update    2
```

I want 3 of those to "belong" to the 2nd bug report. Is there a "best" way to do this? I'm using phpMyAdmin, if that makes any difference.

Thanks for any help setting this up, its much appreciated.

Comment: Not really... i think your approach is good enough. just be sure to add an index for that foreign key

Comment: what do you mean by belong? what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Kasun - Essentially, I want it so that if one of the devs were to add a new update on a particular bug ID, it would add an entry in the `bug_update` table, and the entry in the `bug_update` table would be linked to the row of whichever `bug_id` the update was done on from the `bug_summary` table.

This way, when we pull up a certain bug, our query can easily pull up every entry in the `bug_update` table for a particular bug so we can read it like a journal entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write an on update trigger on `bug_summary` table to create and entry in `bug_update` table anytime the columns you are interested in is updated. You can record the old value and new value of the field that you are interested in. Make sure to record the primary key of the `bug_summary` table as a field in `bug_update` table so you can easily do a join to review updates on a single entry. You might also want to create a field to record a timestamp to know exactly when the update happened.

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/create-the-first-trigger-in-mysql.aspx This article demonstrate the concept

Comment: This sounds like exactly what I wanted! I won't get a chance to test this out until later. Once I do I'll reply and let you know how it goes! :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `bug_update` rows have a many-to-one relationship to `bug_summary` rows. Each summary item can have zero or more update items. That's exactly right for your use case.

You probably should add a serial number of some kind to the  `bug_update` table, or at least a timestamp, so you can present the bug update information in the order it was entered.  (Keep in mind that SQL database records don't have a reliable natural ordering; you have to specify it.)

You could use an autoincrementing update id. Or you could [use `DEFAULT CURRENT TIMESTAMP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html) to do this.

Comment: Thanks so much for this! Yes, this table was going to contain both its own auto-increment ID column and a timestamp for when we query, was just keeping the example simple.

Do I need to actually "link" them in any way in the database? Or would I just handle that in the PHP query when it inserts the new entry into the table?

Comment: You certainly can use `bug_update.bug_id_for_update` as a foreign key to `bug_summary.bug_id`. Docs here. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html This should be the subject of another question.